# Sharepoint WSP deployment problem

Tags: sharepoint-server, solution-package, asp

Im working on a project that implements a solution for managing specific types of records for a client. The solution has two projects to it: a project containing the lists(1) and a project containing the web parts based on asp pages(2).

Project 2 also has a file that has been generated by spmetal. It is used to communicate with the Sharepoint lists. The solution is installed at one of our clients (on a test and a development environment).

A short while ago the responsibilities for the solution as transferred to me. I have setup a new test environment, installed the lists and installed the solution. It works fine.

Just after that i had to make a change. I updated my test environment and it works. Now i tried to install the solution on the clients test environment and i get the following message: Unfortunately, something went wrong. It redirect me to an item in the logging (correlation id): one of the field types are not installed properly. 0x81020014

It does not however state what field is incorrect.

Edit: im adding some of the logging:

```
01/25/2017 09:56:23.93  
w3wp.exe (0x30FC)                           
0x271C  SharePoint Foundation           
General                         
xxpm    
High        
Unable to execute query: Error 0x81020014   
3f70ce9d-421e-e02c-0352-489657d89211
=========================================
01/25/2017 09:56:23.93  
w3wp.exe (0x30FC)                           
0x271C  SharePoint Foundation           
General                         
8kh7    
High        
Een of meer veldtypen is niet goed geïnstalleerd. Ga naar de pagina met instellingen voor de lijst en verwijder deze velden.<nativehr>0x81020014</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>  3f70ce9d-421e-e02c-0352-489657d89211
=========================================
01/25/2017 09:56:23.93  
w3wp.exe (0x30FC)                           
0x271C  SharePoint Foundation           
General                         
aix9j   
High        
SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2: UserPrincipalName=, AppPrincipalName= ,pSqlClient=<null> ,bstrUrl=http://spbatest01/Records ,bstrListName={0E88BB5C-0F5D-478B-B467-AC709702E887} ,bstrViewName=<null> ,bstrViewXml=<View><Query><Where><And><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" /><Value Type="ContentTypeId">0x0100</Value></BeginsWith><Eq><FieldRef Name="Record" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Lookup">40</Value></Eq></And></Where><OrderBy Override="TRUE"><FieldRef Name="Volgorde" /></OrderBy></Query><ViewF ,fSafeArrayFlags=SAFEARRAYFLAG_NONE   3f70ce9d-421e-e02c-0352-489657d89211
=========================================
01/25/2017 09:56:23.93  
w3wp.exe (0x30FC)                           
0x271C  SharePoint Foundation           
General                         
ai1wu   
Medium      
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Een of meer veldtypen is niet goed geïnstalleerd. Ga naar de pagina met instellingen voor de lijst en verwijder deze velden.<nativehr>0x81020014</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>, StackTrace:    bij Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()     bij Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.GetEnumerator()     bij Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.SPQueryable.<GetSPDataListItems>d__9.MoveNext()     bij System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()     bij Temp.Record.ControlTemplates.Temp.Record.RecordUserControl.LoadData(RecordController RecordController, RecordListFieldsContentType Record, Int32 currentID)     bij Temp.Record.ControlTemplates.Temp.Record.RecordUserControl.<>c__Di... 3f70ce9d-421e-e02c-0352-489657d89211
=========================================
01/25/2017 09:56:23.93* 
w3wp.exe (0x30FC)                           
0x271C  SharePoint Foundation           
General                         
ai1wu   
Medium      
...splayClass16_0.<Inititialize>b__0()     
bij Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__3()     
bij Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     
bij Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)     
bij Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     
bij Temp.Record.ControlTemplates.Temp.Record.RecordUserControl.Inititialize(String selectedRecord, Int32 currentID)     
bij Temp.Record.ControlTemplates.Temp.Record.RecordUserControl.LoadRecord(RecordController RecordController)     
bij Temp.Record.ControlTemplates.Temp.Record.RecordUserControl.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs...    3f70ce9d-421e-e02c-0352-489657d89211
=========================================
01/25/2017 09:56:23.93* 
w3wp.exe (0x30FC)                           
0x271C  SharePoint Foundation           
General                         
ai1wu   
Medium      
... e)     bij System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     
bij System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     
bij System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     
bij System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)     
bij Temp.Record.Webpart.Webpart.CreateChildControls()     
bij System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     
bij System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     
bij System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     
bij System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     
bij System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     
bij System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     
bij System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     
bij System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     
bij System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean incl...   3f70ce9d-421e-e02c-0352-489657d89211
```

Comment: Did you check the ULS log by that correlation id? 
I suspect that there is problem with lookup column or site column.

Comment: I did, it specifies that there is a column problem, however it does not say what column.

Comment: It definitely should be in the logs.

Comment: I have found a post on the internet stating that i should open the list in sharepoint desinger, and recreate the lookup column: https://sharepointsd.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/one-or-more-field-types-are-not-installed-properly-go-to-the-list-settings-page-to-delete-these-fields/ The list does however not show up on the sharepoint designer.

Comment: Change the verbosity of the logs it will tell you which field is incorrectly installed (my bet is that filed is installed twice and original was not updated I had it myself more than few times) Get-SPLogLevel #check logging lever
Clear-SPLogLevel  #set logging lever to default. 
Set-SPLogLevel -EventSeverity verbose -TraceSeverity verboseex  #Set max level of logging.

Comment: Can a field be installed twice? How would that happen? I understand that i can install the list twice, however just one field? I do think however that either a field or a list has been installed twice. Ill work with that verbosity level.